# How can i delete this line in a file?

Tags: html, unix

i've got an HTML-File like this:

```
<script src="jljlaösf" type="module"></script><script nomodule defer></script><script src="soll bleiben" defer ></script><script src="asdflöksfndakhfsakö" type="module"></script>
```

Now, I have to delete all tags with type="module" in it using RegEx- or best SED in a UNIX Shell - no matter what is written in the src="xxxxx" attribute (the only thing that can differ)

Can someone please help me out on this one?

Greets Andi

Comment: The obligatory [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/7552) link

Comment: `grep -v module` or `sed '/module/d`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Ei '<.*type="module"><\/script>' htmlfile
```

Enable regular extension with grep through -E and then do an inverse selection with -i/ Search for <...type="module"> and print everything else.